# Counting occurances of n-length word from a string in C

Tags: c

New here and am looking for some help. Trying to teach myself C and found some assignments online. (https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node7.html) Basically just trying to creature part of that assignment (Exercise 12337) by finding only one n-length word instead of multiples. My program right now counts the total number of words, but I don't know how to get beyond that point to start singling out words based on their length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int words(const char lne[ ]);

int main()
{
    char lne[60], name[25]=""; 
    FILE *fp;

    printf("Enter name of the input file: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    if ((fp = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("File cannot be opened!");
    }

    else
    {
        int cntf=-1, cntw=-1;
        while (fgets(lne, sizeof lne, fp))
        cntf += words(lne);
        //cntw += letter(lne);
        printf("\nThe most frequent word length is %d", cntf );
        printf("\nThe message includes %d words of that length", cntf);


        fclose(fp);
    }

    return 0;
}

int words(const char lne[])
{
    int i, count=0;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(lne); i++)
    {
        if (lne[i] == ' '||lne[i] == '\t'||lne[i] == '\n')
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Could you give more information about what you understand? Do you fully understand the code you show, or did you copy parts of it and don't know how some of it works?  Could you show in pseudocode your best guess as to what the solution would look like?

Comment: The easiest way to do it would be to pass a separate (zero initialized) array of at least 27 chars to `words` and then within `words` get the length of each word read and increment that `index` of the array. (e.g. if your word is 6-chars, then in your length array do `larray[6]++`. When you have read your file, `larray` will contain the number of words at each index of that length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When measuring the frequency of just about any occurrence within a range (word lengths, character occurrences, etc.), one very simple approach is to declare an array with at least the maximum number of elements in the range (e.g. if you were counting the number of occurrences of `a-z` you would need an array of at least `26` elements). (for word lengths, you need an array of at least `27` -- the length of the longest word in the unabridged dictionary). You can always include a few extra elements to insure you cover the range if the range in uncertain.

The array must be initialized to `0`. Then for each occurrence, continuing with the `a-z` example, each time an `a` is encountered, you would increment the index associated with `a` (e.g. `0`, `b=1`, `c=2`) and so on. So when an `a` s encountered, and your array name is `charfreq` you would increment

```
charfreq[0]++;
```

After you read all characters and increment the associated index, then the value in `charfreq[0]` is the number of `a`'s, `charfreq[1]` the number of `b`'s, and so on.

You can use that exact approach to collect the frequency of word sizes as well. Before you can find the frequency of the lengths, you, of course, must find the number of words. While you can manually find the number of words by counting the whitespace separators per-line and adding `1`, that does nothing to let you get the length of each word (you can walk 2 pointers down the string as you count whitespace terminating/restoring after each word and taking the pointer difference), but the C library has `strtok` to help tokenize the line for you.

When you tokenize the line (regardless how you do it), you simply need to take the length of each token (word) and update your frequency array -- and you are done. Your `words` function could be written as follows with the help of `strtok` (note `strtok` modifies the original string, so you will need a copy if you must preserve the original)

```
int words (const char *buf, const char *delims, int *freq)
{
    char tmp[MAXC] = "";    /* temp array to hold buf as */
    char *p;                /* strtok modifies original  */
    int cnt = 0;

    strncpy (tmp, buf, sizeof tmp); /* copy buf to tmp & tokenize */
    for (p = strtok (tmp,delims); p; p = strtok (NULL, delims)) {
        cnt++;
        freq[strlen(p)]++;
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

Putting those pieces together, an noting that filenames are usually passed as arguments, you could do something like the following to read/process words from a file (or from `stdin` by default):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXF = 32, MAXC = 256 };

int words (const char *buf, const char *delims, int *freq);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    char *delims = " ,.\t\n";      /* delimiters for strtok */
    int cntw = 0, i, midx = 0, mfreq = 0;
    int freq[MAXF] = {0};
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file is open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp))     /* read each line */
        cntw += words (buf, delims, freq);  /* call words     */

    i = MAXF;
    while (i--)          /* find longest most frequent length */
        if (freq[i] > mfreq) {   /* in mfreq, which occurs at */
            mfreq = freq[i];     /* midx - most frequent idx  */
            midx = i;
        }

    /* output results */
    printf (" \n There are '%d' words in the file.\n", cntw);
    printf (" The most frequent word length is '%d'\n", midx);
    printf (" The message includes '%d' words of that length.\n\n", 
            mfreq);

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}

int words (const char *buf, const char *delims, int *freq)
{
    char tmp[MAXC] = "";    /* temp array to hold buf as */
    char *p;                /* strtok modifies original  */
    int cnt = 0;

    strncpy (tmp, buf, sizeof tmp); /* copy buf to tmp & tokenize */
    for (p = strtok (tmp,delims); p; p = strtok (NULL, delims)) {
        cnt++;
        freq[strlen(p)]++;
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat ../dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/wordsmfreq <../dat/captnjack.txt

 There are '16' words in the file.
 The most frequent word length is '4'
 The message includes '4' words of that length.
```

**Using `strcspn` Instead of `strtok`**

There is another function in the library that is worthwhile here, `strcspn`. It will scan a string for occurrences not contained in the delimiter It returns the length of the initial segment not containing any of the reject character in the `delims` list. You can use the function to make repeated calls on `tmp` while advancing a pointer over `tmp` to accomplish what `strtok` does. (without also having to call `strlen`)

Look over the example and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is quite a bit overwhelming to show a beginner.

Comment: I agree, but the task of counting word length frequency isn't exactly a small task in and of itself. It would be a whole lot messier to have walked a start and end pointer down `tmp` taking the pointer difference for the length. There just wasn't a simple way to handle collecting frequency of lengths from a file of unknown length that looked any simpler. Maybe I missed something obvious?

Comment: You have a point! I'll think about how this could possibly be improved. `strtok` may not be necessary, for instance.

Comment: Thank you! This helps. I am digesting all this right now, and have kinda been messing around with the code to see what everything does. One thing I did notice is that it always seems to return a value of 4 for "most frequent word".

Comment: If you dump the array (or just count the 4 letter word `This`, `tale`, `Jack`, and `Seas` those are the 4character-words that are the must frequent in the passage. However, I have just spotted a problem with that index I must fix -- hold on `:)`

Comment: @TheUnicorn. the issue was in the final output of the number of words of that length. I had `freq[mfreq]` as that value, but I actually needed the index where `mfreq` occurred, not `mfreq` itself. So I added `midx` as a variable to hold the index where the most frequent length word occurs. Using `freq[midx]` gives the correct number of times the most frequent length word appears. Let me know if you have any more questions, I'm happy to help -- good catch! Also, if you are stumbling over `strtok`, there is another function `strcspn` that is useful here as well. I'll drop an example.

Comment: Also be aware how you iterate through `freq` to find the word with the most frequent use. You can have multiple word length that appear the same number of times. Like `is`, `of`, `So`, `On` are words that also appear `4` times in the passage. So to find the longest, you would need to iterate from the highest index to the lowest.

Comment: Again, thank you so much. Very helpful, and I will continue to mess around with it to learn some more of the code.